# Как подключить общую папку в гостевой Debian на virtualbox (родительская ос win7)?

Tags: debian, virtualbox

Решил я установить virtualbox 5 и протестировать разные операционные системы, начал с разных
linux (первыми выбрал Ubuntu (потому что, как-то знакомо звучит название), Debian (прочитал, что на нем домашний сервер поднять можно,
и для этого Debian как раз и рекомендуют), Kali-Linux ( проверка сетевой безопасности и все такое).
Для своих экспериментов брал образы с сайта http://www.osboxes.org/virtualbox-images/

Информацию узнал из статьи http://alv.me/?p=10087

С Ubuntu 15.10 64 bit все прошло на ура. Легко установились дополнения гостевой системы, общая папка была доступна
 по адресу `/media/sf_namesharefolder`. Также работает drug-n-drop (перетаскивание файлов из гостевой и родительской ос). Работает звук.

В Kali-linux 2.0 64 bit установились дополнения гостевой системы, доступна общая папка. Но нет звука. Как вылечить звук
 решения не нашел (гугление тоже не помогло). Если кто знает напишите как это можно сделать.

И самым сложным оказался Debian Jesie 8.2 64 bit. Во-первых: дополнения гостевой системы установились только из под root (в терминале 
вводим su потом пароль от пользователя под которым зашли в систему (в случае образов с osboxes.org (user - osboxes; пароль - osboxes.org).
И только после этого удалось командой `sh VBoxGuestAdditions.run` установить дополнения гостевой системы. Это помогло с разрешением экрана и тем что теперь можно развернуть на весь экран. Работает звук, что тоже радует а вот общая папка не доступна.

Как настроить для Debian Jesie 8.2 64 bit (в virtualbox) общую папку?

Comment: Есть предложение для пытливых умов. Вот ссылка на образ Debian из сообщения выше: http://www.osboxes.org/debian/
Вдруг есть такой человек, кто сможет разобраться и правильно установить дополнения гостевой ос и настроить общую папку.
И если этот опыт удастся, то поделиться с общественностью его результатом, было бы выше всяких похвал.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

После нескольких дней мучений проблема была решена!
Установились все дополнения гостевой системы. Окно гостевой Debian разворачивается на весь экран.
Есть звук. Работает буфер обмена (drug-n-drop в том числе). И барабанная дробь... Доступна общая папка!

Что для этого потребовалось:

(Сам Virtualbox версии 5.012 с пакетом гостевых дополнений был уже установлен)

1. Установить с нуля чистый образ Debian 8.2 x64 с официального сайта проекта Debian 
   ссылка прилагается:  https://www.debian.org/distrib/netinst 
   Я использовал мини образ размером порядка 240 мб для 64 разрядной системы.

2.Образ был смонтирован и установлен (помогло вот это видео https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rP_NEAGmGPo ).

3. Далее из под root (вводим команду su а затем пароль, который вы задали при установке образа) были установленны
   следующие пакеты (даже не знаю которого из них больше всего не хватало):
   (взято было из обсуждения вот по этой ссылке https://askubuntu.com/questions/287205/building-the-main-guest-additions-module-fail  )

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install dkms

sudo apt-get install  build-essential

sudo apt-get install  virtualbox-guest-x11 (вот эта команда не сработала)

sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic

sudo apt-get install linux-headers-virtual

4. После перезагрузки общая папка появилась по адресу /media/sf_nameYourFolder.
   Но она была еще недоступна (потребовалось добавить прав текущему пользователю):

Запустим терминал 
Добавляем нового пользователя к директории.
sudo adduser user_name vboxsf
Вместо user_name указываем себя, своё имя, под которым вас знает система. Чтобы изменения вступили в силу — перезагрузим систему.

Вот после всех этих манипуляций наступил долгожданный успех!

(вот ссылка на сообщение об успешной установке дополнений гостевой системы:  http://joxi.ru/KAgZaxBSg5qW82 
которую я так жаждал получить.)

Надеюсь мои мучения будут кому-то полезны. И позволят не наступать на те же грабли:)
И спасибо всем кто пытался мне помочь. Особенно помог совет "установки чистого исошника"

Comment: В общем диагноз - криворукие китайцы в готовом образе накосячили

Answer (score 1):

Подозреваю примерно так:
sudo mount -t vboxsf wd ~/share/

Самба именно в этом механизме не нужна. VBox делает своё виртуальное устройство.
Надеюсь, что настройки в самом [виртуалбоксе](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#sharedfolders) при этом верны, каталог есть, доступ к нему разрешен и все нужные опции выставлены.

Но на будущее лучше всё же научиться работать с самбой и расшаривать по сети каталоги.

Comment: @Влад ответ обновлен, читайте. я постарался ключевые моменты кратко пояснить. дальше придется самому осваивать Debian и иже с ним (на текущем ресурсе материала хватает), уж не взыщите...

Comment: Выполнил ваши инструкции: скачал образ virtualbox/5.0.0_RC3/, распаковал, запустил из терминала с root правами. Установщик удалил раннее установленную версию (5.0.12)

Дальше пошли сбои: 

gcc utility was not found.

на приложенном ниже скриншоте прекрасно видны все сбои:


http://joxi.ru/8AnxkJbSqNEeOm


ссылка на скриншот лога из установки:
http://joxi.ru/zANd9n6hl1aWEm

Comment: gcc добавит команда sudo apt-get install build-essential , похоже что образ совсем урезанный

Comment: @Влад **apt-get install build-essential module-assistant**. 
ранее был какой-то опыт работы с Linux?

Comment: apt-get install build-essential     apt-get install module-assistant эти команды тоже не срабатывают пишет, что недоступно, скриншот прилагается: http://joxi.ru/MAj3OyBhvdJKYr    Опыт обращения с linux минимальный (как консоль открыть, как по папкам бегать). Сейчас скачал мини образ с официального Debian.org его буду пробовать ставить. Не пойдет если, vmware тогда буду пытать:) Что-то уже спортивный интерес какой-то появился добиться результата.

Comment: @Влад для того чтобы разобраться лучше не качать готовое и не знать как этим пользоваться а начать , например с того, что скачать исошник дистрибутива и ставить систему самому с нуля. возникнут вопросы - есть гугл, книги и т.п. а так нужно кучу вещей объяснять. ответ дан но результата нету - ни в вашем опыте ни в рейтиге тех кто давал ответы.

Comment: Чистым исошником и займусь:)

Comment: Чистый образ установленный с нуля успеха тоже не дал:(   Еще на момент загрузки операционки промелкивает сообщение что VBox service fail. Надо на vmware попробовать завиртуалить Debian.

Comment: @Влад **usermod -a -G vboxusers osboxes**. и попробуйте переустановить сам virtualbox.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34357/discussion-between--and-).

Comment: @Влад там проблеммы с сетью (настройки гостевой ОС+настройки виртуалбокса).

Comment: Спасибо! Ваш совет установить с чистого iso помог решить проблему:)

Answer (score 0):

на Debian необходимо настроить и установить (если не устанавливался во время установки Debian) пакет **Samba**. пример:

http://debian-help.ru/articles/ustanovka-nastroika-samba-debian/

так же, в Virtualbox есть Shared Folders (как точно по-русски не помню, у меня все на английском)

добавка:
http://geckich.blogspot.com/2012/02/samba-debian-linux.html

**VirtualBox Guest Additions** (дополнения, кратко)

общий список:

http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox

для версии VirtualBox 5 (5.0.0)

http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.0.0_RC3/

качаем к себе iso-файл (образ), сохраняем, например, в /home/<ваше_имя_пользователя>/vbox. образ можно просто распаковать (в Debian архиваторов хватает) в эту самую папку. в составе образа есть файлы autorun.sh, runasroot.sh, VBoxLinuxAdditions.run.
атрибут +x (исполнение) уже установлен, нужно просто запустить. для примера использую файл VBoxLinuxAdditions.run. открываем терминал, переходим туда куда  разархивирован образ

```
cd /home/<ваше_имя_пользователя>/vbox
```

и:

получение привилегий рут:

`sudo -s`

(если **sudo** установлен и настроен то спросит пароль вашего пользователя, который был задан в процессе установки)

или

`su` (спросит пароль суперпользователя root, который был задан в процессе установки)

затем

```
./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
```

если атрибут **+x** таки не установлен (думаю, это поймете по ходу дела) то

```
chmod +x VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
```

и снова

```
./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
```

P.S.:
сетевой интерфейс гостевой ОС лично я ставлю как **bridge** но можно и **nat**

Comment: Команда на установку  #aptitude install samba samba-client     просит официального диска amd 64 binary вот ссылка на скриншот: http://joxi.ru/LmGaBLnHRB18XA

Comment: Также просмотр установленных пакетов показал что в системе есть следующие: 
samba-dsdb-modules
samba-libs:amd64                        Они как-то меняют погоду?

Comment: Проблему с требованием диска решил. В файле /etc/apt/sources.list заккоментировал строчку вида: deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux testing _Jesie_ - Official Snapshot amd64 DVD Binary-1 20090908-00:50]/ Jesie contrib main

Comment: samba samba-client установил.

Comment: @Влад тут не получится расписать и объяснить все нюансы сетевого взаимодействия операционных систем, протоколов и т.п. (@Алексей Присяжный написал верно, разобраться нужно самому). далее, по ссылке - пример настройки samba:
http://geckich.blogspot.com/2012/02/samba-debian-linux.html
но для понимания того что требует понимания придется или разбираться самому или задать еще множество вопросов и, в итоге, разбираться самому ... 
P.S.: ссылка добавлена в ответ

Comment: Samba не смог настроить:(  Файлы ее конфига пока для меня сложны.  Думаю надо копать все-таки в сторону дополнений гостевой системы. Что-то там не установилось из-за этого и не работает общая папка и буфер обмена.